# Tensorflow Suppressing Warning messages

Tags: tensorflow

When I run my program I keep getting the following message all the time at the beginning.

```
2020-01-30 22:30:20.071341: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-01-30 22:30:20.211074: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7fd9662a5830 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-01-30 22:30:20.211123: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
```

Is it even necessary? How do I suppress this?

Answer (score 0):

Define this at the top of your file

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').disabled = True
```